# PUT method is not working in front end but works in Postman

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, put

Please, help me. I am doing PERN stack app, and I can't understand why my PUT method is not working in front end but works in Postman perfectly. When I add a todo - "drink water" for example, in database id appears as should "drink water" and in fron end as well it appears, but when I edit that todo  in front end it's null in database and front end as well,
looks like that: `description {id: 56, todo: null}`
Here is a code of EditTodo.js:

```
export default function EditTodo({ todo }) {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(todo);
  console.log("todos", todo);
  console.log("description", description);
  //   Edit function
  const editText = async (id) => {
    try {
      const body = { description };
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/todos/${id}`, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
      });
      console.log("response", response);
      window.location = "/";
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
  };
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn btn-warning"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#myModal"
      >
        Edit
      </button>

      <div className="modal" id="myModal">
        <div className="modal-dialog">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h4 className="modal-title">Edit Todo</h4>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="close"
                data-dismiss="modal"
              ></button>
            </div>

            <div className="modal-body">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                value={description.todo}
                onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="modal-footer">
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-warning"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                onClick={() => editText(todo.id)}
              >
                Edit
              </button>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-danger"
                data-dismiss="modal"
              >
                Close
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Looks like EditText function is not executed when I edit the todo.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you set the `todo`? A `put` request replaces the current values with new ones. If you only set the `description` property but leave the `todo` out, it will overwrite it with an empty string, clearing any data you had in there. Either set the old value of the `todo` before making your `put` request or use a `patch` instead. A patch only affect certain selected values instead of everything. Anyway, it's still very possible to do this with a `put` instead.

Try creating a useEffect where you set your todo to state.

Something like this:

```
    const todoVar = description.find((desc)=> desc.id === todo.id);
    
    useEffect(()=>{
      if(todoVar){
        setDescription(description.todo)
      }
    },[todoVar, setDescription])
```

Basically, you want to set the `todo` value from your database to it's original value before making your `PUT` request. This way it won't be empty/null.

Comment: Should I re-do my query in back end and replace PUT method by PATCH?

Comment: You could try that, alternatively you could do something like this with the put (I'll edit my comment)

Comment: Changed, but still that problem(((